# Function per iteration in 2 list/arrays

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, iteration

I'm trying to iterate over 2 lists in python, and for each iteration, process a function. 
Let's say A = [40,30,25] and B = [45,35,25]. (However, in my actual application A and B are arrays of sentences)

I want my resultant function to do something like this:

```
For A[1] & B[1]:
    print("Sum: ", A[1] + B[1])
For A[1] & B[2]: 
    print("Sum: ", A[1] + B[2])
For A[1] & B[3]:
    print("Sum: ", A[1] + B[3])

For A[2] & B[1]:
    print("Sum: ", A[2] + B[1])
For A[2] & B[2]:
    print("Sum: ", A[2] + B[2])
For A[2] & B[3]:
    print("Sum: ", A[2] + B[3])

For A[3] & B[1]:
    print("Sum: ", A[3] + B[1])
For A[3] & B[2]:
    print("Sum: ", A[3] + B[2])
For A[3] & B[3]:
    print("Sum: ", A[3] + B[2])
```

I do understand that this is in essence a nested for loop, but I can't seem to run it exactly how I want it to right now. Through my own research, it seemed like I needed to use itertools zip function to process correctly.

My current code is as follows:

```
for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(lst1, lst2, fillvalue=None):
        print("X: ",x, "\tY: ",y, "\nZ: ", nlp(x).similarity(nlp(y)))
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for `[f(x, y) for x in A for y in B]` (where `f` represents whatever you want to do with `x` and `y`)?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Well what I really need to do is compare similarities between each element in A with each element in B. If similarity is achieved, I save it to another array. Not 100% familiar with the mathematical expression, but here's what I'm looking for in words!

Comment: "If similarity is achieved" - what will this mean in terms of the output for `nlp(x).similarity(nlp(y)`?

Comment: I'm actually not sure if I have the x/y correctly done in my own code. Though through a few trials, "nlp(x).similarity(nlp(y)" returns a float between 0 and 1 (1 being identical, 0 being completely dissimilar). X and Y are strings (sentences, not words)

Comment: In that case how about something like `import math; result = [z for z in (nlp(x).similarity(nlp(y) for x in A for y in B) if math.isclose(z, 1.)]`.

Comment: That will work! I'll have to do much more than that for my actual application, I was just having trouble with the mapping of A1->B1,2,3 & A2->B1,2,3, & A3->B1,2,3. Seems like Beth's suggestion will help be achieve that. Thanks for the prompt help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* to user itertools. @coldpseed's comment is a good concise answer. Writing it more expanded would look like:

```
for x in A:
    for y in B:
        print("X: ",x, "\tY: ",y, "\nZ: ", nlp(x).similarity(nlp(y)))
```

or alternately using indices

```
for i in range (0, len(A)):
    for j in range (0, len(B)):
        x = A[i]
        y = B[j]
        print("X: ",x, "\tY: ",y, "\nZ: ", nlp(x).similarity(nlp(y)))
```

Comment: This is fine, but needs a little work. OP will most likely want to retain the result. I suggest, if using nested loops, to initialise an empty list and append to it. You are also free to add my comment into your answer, if you know what it is doing.

Comment: 3rd nitpick: if there is a good way to do something, you almost never want to recommend a worse solution as an alternative. In this situation, I would recommend dropping the suggestion to iterate over the indices, it is almost certainly not required here and the poorer of the two options.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. I'll leave it as is, because on point 1 it seems to have solved OP's problem using his example function, and on point 2 I don't think it's objectively worse to use indices. Thanks!